# Как задать условие последнему элементу массива с состоянием

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, handlers, usestate

Калькулятор.

По нажатию на кнопки вызывается `clickNumHandler`
как задать условие - проверять последний элемент массива на тип число, чтобы нельзя было ставить несколько знаков подряд.
если последний элемент число - добавлять на экран айди нажатой кнопки.

`displayNum` - собирает все нажатые числа, символы и выводит на экран.

нерабочий пример кода:

```
const [displayNum, setDisplayNum] = useState([])

const clickNumHandler = (e) => {
   typeof displayNum[displayNum.length-1] == 'number' || displayNum == []
   ? setDisplayNum([...displayNum + (e.currentTarget.id)])
   : console.log('NaN')
```

кнопки

```
const numDiv = (id) => {
    return(
        <div id={id} onClick={props.onClickNum}>{id}</div>
    )
}
 {numDiv(1)}
```

Comment: `displayNum == []` всегда возвращает false. Дополните пример большими подробностями и разметкой, что именно за кнопки, что такое ваш displayNum и откуда берется, какой результат вы хотите увидеть

Comment: что такое displayNum написано чуть выше кода, в него записывается каждая нажатая кнопка.  кнопки обычные дивы с id таким же как название, у кнопки 1 id 1, и этот 1 id используется для записи в displayNum, видно в функции. И на них событие онклик  который вызывает clickNumHandler, вопрос сейчас дополню

Comment: onClickNum в пропс вызывает clickNumHandler

Comment: а displayNum == [] служит в качестве альтернативы typeof displayNum[displayNum.length-1] == 'number' в случае если это первый элемент

Comment: Можете оформить ваш пример в песочнице, например в [codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/). Если кнопок несколько, а обработчик с состоянием один, не понятно, какой результат у вас должен получиться

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/dazzling-banach-dfhl7c?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark         смотрите в полноэкранном пожалуйста, верстка пока не адаптивная

Comment: Потыкал. Нажатые цифры собираются и выводятся

Comment: верно, но вопрос о условии

Comment: нужна логика для ввода. Если последний элемент цифра - можно любой символ, если символ - можно только цифру. Это нужно чтобы избежать нескольких символов подряд. После точки не может быть арифметического знака или другой точки, только цифра. Я пытаюсь понять как получить последний элемент массива displayNum, и проверить его на соответствие типу числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения:

```
const clickNumHandler = (e) => {
    const prevDN = [...displayNum]; .// Создаем копию массива
    if (prevDN.length) { // Если в массиве уже есть элементы
      if (
        // последний элемент число
        !isNaN(+prevDN[prevDN.length - 1]) ||
        // или последний не число и добавляется число
        (isNaN(+prevDN[prevDN.length - 1]) && !isNaN(+e.currentTarget.id))
      ) {
        prevDN.push(e.currentTarget.id);
        setDisplayNum(prevDN);
      }
    } else {
      // Первый элемент массива. Тут можно добавить проверку
      // это это число или допустимый знак(например минус)
      prevDN.push(e.currentTarget.id);
      setDisplayNum(prevDN);
    }
  };
```

Еще можно запоминать последний введенный символ, что бы постоянно не обращаться к массиву.

Так же стоит определить набор допустимых первых знаков(вряд ли можно начинать математическое выражение со знака умножения или деления).

Comment: большое спасибо!